# Javascript error when using .matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check and make sure that a variable contains ONLY numerals 0-9 or a period or a comma.  Anything else should be rejected.

I've set up a simple IF statement in a function that I thought would work but it's not:

```
function numCheck(source) {
  if (!(source.matches("[0-9.,]*"))) {
    alert('Number');
  }
  else {
    alert('Not a number');
  }
}
```

Nothing happens.  I can call the function without the if statement and it works, but somehow I'm just not correctly doing the syntax.

Comment: Do you mean that `,,,,,` or `,,,,....` etc should be considered a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using regex delimiters and line start/end anchors.

It should be:

```
source.match(/^[0-9.,]*$/)
```

Comment: Although it's not recommended, you *can* pass a string as a regex to `match()` and it will be implicitly converted to a regex object.

Comment: Thanks for the great comments/help.  This was what I was looking for.  Had cut and pasted from elsewhere not realizing "matches" wasn't correct.  And knowing the right regex is great too!  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

`matches()` isn't a method in the standard library, however, [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is.

In fact, you're probably better off using something like this...

```
var looksLikeANumber = /^[\d.,]+$/.test(source);
```

I used [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) because you don't need the power of `match()`, which will return captured groups, etc. This way, you also get implicit casting of `source` to a string for free (if a number was passed in, you'd be in trouble as `match()` isn't on `Number.prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var match = /^[0-9.,]*$/.exec(this.value); // value to be matched
   if (!match) {
       alert('invalid');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go a bit further with this regex and using `.test`:

```
var result = /^\d*[\d,.]\d*$/.test(string);
```

To make sure there is at least one number (it can accept more) and only 1 period or 1 dot.